# Dashboard problem after installing reverse proxy server

Tags: dashboard, nginx

We recently tightened up the URLs on the server so that everything now goes through https://domain_name.com. There was initially a problem with the dashboard widgets not loading (just hanging on "Loading..."), so I installed nginx reverse proxy, which stopped the "Loading..." issue, but now I get the following displayed where each widget would be:

**Not Found

The requested URL /administrator/ was not found on this server.

Apache Server at domain_name.com Port 443**

Everything else is working fine. It's just a problem with the dashboard widgets. Any ideas where to start looking for a solution? Thanks.

CiviCRM 4.6.8, Joomla 3.4.3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be a hosting problem. The /etc/hosts file had two conflicting entries, associating the host name with two different IP addresses. So I removed one of them, and Bob was my uncle.

Comment: Could you explain how you set up the reverse proxy with CiviCRM? I'm running into issue after issue. Are you using static base_url?

Comment: Reverse proxy is a hosting matter - nothing to do with CiviCRM. You'll have to look for help relaing to your specific server setup. Apart from that, it was five years ago, and I've forgotten everything. Sorry.