# Why is my dashboard showing 503 errors? Is this a host issue or a civi config issue?

Tags: error, configuration

Civi seems to be working normally, but all dashboard items are showing 503 errors (ngnix).

Any ideas of what to check? Hosted on Arvixe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some issues with the dashboard have been fixed in the upcoming 4.7.11 release. See [CRM-16035: Dashlet refresh can crash server / Replace use of HTTP_Request](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-16035) and [CRM-17663: Dashlet code improvements](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-17663) for details.

There are quite a few existing questions on dashboard issues on this site - you'll find some good answers there I'm sure for dealing with CiviCRM below 4.7.11.

- [The dashboard does not render](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/3426/the-dashboard-does-not-render)
- [CiviCRM Dashboard Not Working - WordPress installation](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/12172/civicrm-dashboard-not-working-wordpress-installation)
- [Dashboard problem after installing reverse proxy server](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/6282/dashboard-problem-after-installing-reverse-proxy-server)
- [CiviCRM Dashboard Hangs for 5+ minutes](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/12886/civicrm-dashboard-hangs-for-5-minutes)

Once 4.7.11 releases, that should resolve your problem.