# Drupal Views in CiviCRM Dashlets -- Network Error

Tags: drupal-views, dashlet

I've created a Drupal View as a CiviCRM Dashlet. I can access it if I go directly to the path.  I can select it and pull it onto my dashboard, but I can't access data on my dashboard. I get Network Error -- Unable to reach the server. Please refresh this page in your browser and try again.

CiviCRM version 4.7.16
Same dashlet works with Version 4.7.6

Comment: changed your 'can' to a 'can't' as assume that is what you meant: "but I can access data on my dashboard"

Comment: pls remove your 'answer' (as it isn't an 'answer') and add as a comment. also add your civicrm version since there were issues with dashboard issues. Do civi dashlets show? You may want to review the other tickets listed here http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/14395/why-is-my-dashboard-showing-503-errors-is-this-a-host-issue-or-a-civi-config-is/14400 in case any of those ring bells for your situation